# Undefined reference to deleted file?

Tags: qt, undefined-reference

I have accidently added a new class to my application, instead of only a header file. So I removed the `.cpp` file because it was almost empty (its only a small class, a header file is enough for it)..

Now however I cannot compile my app, it keeps giving me errors of undefined references to the `.cpp` file.

Then, I made a new clean application and I copied the content class by class but it still keeps bugging for undefined references to the `.cpp` file.

Jst to give more information, the application starts bugging as soon as I add `ListObject.h`.

```
#ifndef LISTOBJECT_H
#define LISTOBJECT_H

#include <QObject>

class ListObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ListObject(QString &Name, QString &ID) : name(Name), id(ID) {}
    ~ListObject();

    QString Name() const { return id + ":" + name; }
    QString getId() const { return id; }
    QString getName() const { return name; }

private:
    QString name;
    QString id;
};

#endif // LISTOBJECT_H
```

There is nothing in it that connects to the `.cpp` file and I have also removed the source entry from the `.pro` file and tried to delete the `user.pro` file. Nothing worked. If anyone knows where this is coming from, I would be really glad.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the exact error output the compiler returns? Please also add a block to your destructor: ``~ListObject(){};``

Comment: @SebastianLange hahahaha no way,, the block did the trick!  i cant believe i didnt see that.. thanks alot!!

oh and just for the info, here is the error:

moc_listobject.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `ListObject::~ListObject()'

Answer (score 0):

the destructor was missing blocks!